# Raoul Bott's quote on Morse Theory cited by Bestvina and Kahle: where is it from?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, ho.history-overview

I wanted to properly cite the following awesome quote:

> Every mathematician has a secret weapon. Mine is Morse theory. - Raoul Bott

Now this has been attributed to Bott in precisely two places that I can find: the older of the two is Bestvina's work on PL Morse theory [here](http://www.math.utah.edu/~bestvina/eprints/minicourse.pdf) and the more recent occurrence is in the 14th slide of Kahle's talk available as a rather large pdf file [here](http://matthewkahle.org/sites/default/files/papers/ColoradoState.pdf).

Question:

> What is the original reference for this quote?

I've combed through the likely suspect, *Morse theory indomitable* available [here](http://archive.numdam.org/article/PMIHES_1988__68__99_0.pdf) but the quote does not appear to be in that paper

Comment: Why don't you ask Mladen?

Comment: Good idea, I've just sent him an email. I will post an answer here if and when he responds.

Comment: The quote does sound like Bott, though it's not likely to be found in his formal writings; maybe from a lecture.   Beyond asking Mladen, you might get help from Bob MacPherson (IAS), who was a student of Bott's and edited his multi-volume collected papers (Birkhauser, 1994-1995).    In any case, it is honorable of you to check the folklore, which most of us are happy to pass along whether authentic or not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is Mladen's response to my email asking this question:

> I heard him say it in a colloquium talk in 2001 (I think).

Case closed, unless Bob MacPherson has a different answer.

Comment: M used to paraphrase this pretty frequently, and say that his secret weapon was folding. I didn't know we were the Bott of the joke.